# Does PhantomJS use QtWebKit or Blink?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, chromium, qtwebkit, blink

Does PhantomJS (CasperJS) use WebKit or Chromium as default browser-driver?
If WebKit, is it direct WebKit or qt or gtk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PhantomJS is based on QtWebKit.

The FAQ says:

> Q: Which WebKit version is used by PhantomJS?
>
> A: If you want to know HTML5/CSS3/other features supported by PhantomJS, using WebKit version is not a good idea. See Supported Web Standards documentation page for details.
>
> If you really like to get the WebKit version, find it via the user agent, run the examples/useragent.js. The actual version depends on the libraries with which PhantomJS was compiled.

In PhantomJS 1.9.8 it is 534.34. Based on [this page](http://qnalist.com/questions/5146321/webkit-534-34-when-was-it-released) it was released on 05/05/2011.

[PhantomJS 2 will use 538.1](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/PhantomJS-2) which was released in november 2013:

> As of May 2014 it is based on webkit 538.1 (7 months old).

---

CasperJS runs on top of either PhantomJS (WebKit) or SlimerJS (Gecko). There are currently no other engines available.