# Difference between PhantomJS 2.0 and PhantomJS 1.9

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

Can anyone give me the differences between those versions?

What can I do in version 2 that I could not do in earlier versions?

I use PhantomJS to execute code generated by Selenium. Will be there performance improvements?

Comment: The difference ? Something like 0.1 Phantom JS... That said, what you're asking is called [Release notes](http://phantomjs.org/release-2.0.html)

Comment: @Bartdude Sadly, that page doesn't contain the useful stuff.

Comment: My Bad then... not using it I was supposing release notes were complete as the ones from jQuery can be for example. apparently not :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PhantomJS 2 has a "new" WebKit version underneath. So it changed from 534.34 in PhantomJS 1 to 538.1 in PhantomJS 2. The difference in numbers in this dimension is not big, but there is a more than two year difference between the release of the two WebKit versions. See also: [Does PhantomJS use QtWebKit or Blink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685042/does-phantomjs-use-qtwebkit-or-blink)

It's not that its performance is better, but rather that it supports more up-to-date web standards and APIs, and has less bugs.

Problems in the past:

- `element.click()` was not available on all elements, but only on `<input>` and `<button>` elements. ([Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15739263/1816580))
- PhantomJS has now `Function.prototype.bind` which doesn't need a [shim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26383058/1816580) anymore.
- PhantomJS <1.9.8 used SSLv3 by default [which broke many scripts one day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417660/1816580).
- PhantomJS 1 has a bug with [`:nth-child()` selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28135548/1816580).