# click() function is missing on DOM element in evaluate() in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, click, phantomjs, casperjs

I am seeing different methods on a DOM element in Chrome's console compared to CasperJS. I have the following that I run

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug"
});

var url = 'http://casperjs.org/';

casper.start(url, function() {
  this.echo('sdfsdf');
});

casper.then(function() {
  var link = this.evaluate(function() {
    var b = document.querySelector(".page-header");
    var s = "";

    for (var m in b) {
      if (typeof b[m] === 'function') {
        s += JSON.stringify(m) + " ";
      }
    }
    return s;
  });
  console.log(link);
});

casper.run();
```

It produces

> "children" "childNodes" "insertAdjacentElement" "insertAdjacentHTML"
>   "insertAdjacentText" "setAttribute" "getElementsByTagName"
>   "getAttribute" "querySelectorAll" "webkitMatchesSelector"
>   "getElementsByClassName" "contains" "getBoundingClientRect"
>   "removeAttribute" "querySelector" "hasAttribute" "getAttributeNode"
>   "getAttributeNS" "getElementsByTagNameNS" "removeAttributeNS"
>   "getClientRects" "scrollByPages" "setAttributeNode" "setAttributeNS"
>   "hasAttributeNS" "blur" "scrollIntoViewIfNeeded" "scrollByLines"
>   "setAttributeNodeNS" "removeAttributeNode" "getAttributeNodeNS"
>   "focus" "scrollIntoView" "addEventListener" "appendChild" "cloneNode"
>   "removeChild" "removeEventListener" "compareDocumentPosition"
>   "insertBefore" "hasAttributes" "isSupported" "isEqualNode"
>   "dispatchEvent" "isDefaultNamespace" "hasChildNodes" "normalize"
>   "replaceChild" "isSameNode" "lookupPrefix" "lookupNamespaceURI"

On other hand if I run the following code in Chrome's console

```
var b = document.querySelector(".page-header");
var s = "";
for (var m in b) {
  if (typeof b[m] === 'function') {
    s += JSON.stringify(m) + " ";
  }
}
```

I get the following. Why is the CasperJS missing `click`?

> ""click" "focus" "blur" "hasAttributes" "getAttribute"
>   "getAttributeNS" "setAttribute" "setAttributeNS" "removeAttribute"
>   "removeAttributeNS" "hasAttribute" "hasAttributeNS" "getAttributeNode"
>   "getAttributeNodeNS" "setAttributeNode" "setAttributeNodeNS"
>   "removeAttributeNode" "closest" "matches" "getElementsByTagName"
>   "getElementsByTagNameNS" "getElementsByClassName" "insertAdjacentHTML"
>   "createShadowRoot" "getDestinationInsertionPoints"
>   "requestPointerLock" "getClientRects" "getBoundingClientRect"
>   "scrollIntoView" "insertAdjacentElement" "insertAdjacentText"
>   "scrollIntoViewIfNeeded" "webkitMatchesSelector" "animate" "remove"
>   "webkitRequestFullScreen" "webkitRequestFullscreen" "querySelector"
>   "querySelectorAll" "hasChildNodes" "normalize" "cloneNode"
>   "isEqualNode" "compareDocumentPosition" "contains" "lookupPrefix"
>   "lookupNamespaceURI" "isDefaultNamespace" "insertBefore" "appendChild"
>   "replaceChild" "removeChild" "isSameNode" "addEventListener"
>   "removeEventListener" "dispatchEvent" "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PhantomJS 1.x, then there is support for `click()`, but only on `<input>` and `<button>` elements. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) for more information. Note that PhantomJS 1.x is comparable to Chrome 13 and full support for `click()` was introduced in Chrome 20.

This support was extended to all element types in PhantomJS 2, because it has a [newer Webkit version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557557/1816580) under the hood.

---

Either use CasperJS' `click()`:

```
casper.click(selector);
```

or one of the many workarounds for PhantomJS: [PhantomJS; click an element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15739263/1816580)