# Does PhantomJS support css shapes?

Tags: css, phantomjs, css-shapes

I have made some webpage with css shapes where text align to transparent imgage and in browser everything is ok, but when I render it with PhantomJS it's all messed up. Does PhantomJS support css shapes?

Answer (score 1):

Phantom doesn't support CSS shapes. The current version (2.0.1) is based on a WebKit version that was [released in November 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27687648/1816580). Whereas canisuse.com [reports](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes) that the earliest Safari version (7.1) that had CSS shapes support was [released in September 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history).

Comment: Safari is more or less the only major browser that is based on WebKit, so I use that for comparison.

Comment: is there a chance to support it in future?

Comment: Sure, future versions of PhantomJS can support CSS shapes if the development team decides to change the underlying WebKit engine, but this is usually a very very challenging task, because there are always some breaking changes in newer WebKit versions that require custom patching to make the PhantomJS wrapper around WebKit work. I don't know whether such a major change is on the agenda within the version 2.x.

Comment: By the way, which PhantomJS version do you use? [Modernizr](http://modernizr.github.io/Modernizr/test/) detects CSS shape support for PhantomJS 2.0.0. So, I guess it's not fully implemented.

Comment: I have phantomJS 1.9.8 version

Comment: Then I suggest that you try to use PhantomJS 2.x